# I can not save the for loop of the sequential results in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

My `for` loop algorithm has always different sizes, because of the different outputs of the `seq`, for that reason, I can't save the results. How can I do that? I am stuck on the `mat[?,?]` part of the loop, please look at the example below. How can I do that?

```
d<-data.frame(L1=c(1,6,8), L2=c(3,14,22))
    mat<-matrix(c(0),15,2)

for (i in 1:nrow(d)) {
    x1<-seq(d$L1[i],d$L2[i],2)
    x1
    for (k in seq_along(x1[-1])) {
      
      L1<- x1[k]
      L2<- x1[k+1]
      mat[?,]<- c(L1+L2,L1-L2)
  }
    }
```

In addition, what do you recommend for the `nrow` of the initial matrix `mat` (it is 15 here).

The saving outputs will be,
for `i<-1` and `k<-1`

```
mat[1,]<-c(4,-2),
```

for `i<-2` and `k<-1, k<-2, k<-3` and `k<-4`

```
 mat[2,]<-c(14,-2), mat[3,]<-c(18,-2),mat[4,]<-c(22 ,-2) and mat[5,]<-c(22 ,-2)
```

and so on..

Comment: I think there are better ways to do this without a `for` loop. Can you show what is your expected output for given dataframe `d` ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually, I need it to calculate sth as I am summed and subtracted in this example.

Comment: Is the question clear?

Comment: No, it is not clear for me. Can you show the expected output for the given example?

Comment: I added the saving outputs @RonakShah

Comment: Ok..and can you explain now why the first row is 4 and -2, second row is 14, -2 etc?

Comment: Yes, they are the summation of `L1` and `L2` and I obtained them from the `seq(d$L1[i],d$L2[i],2)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach using `apply` which will :

```
do.call(rbind, apply(d, 1, function(x) {
  x1 <- seq(x[1], x[2], 2)
  cbind(head(x1, -1) + tail(x1, -1), head(x1, -1) - tail(x1, -1))
}))

#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    4   -2
# [2,]   14   -2
# [3,]   18   -2
# [4,]   22   -2
# [5,]   26   -2
# [6,]   18   -2
# [7,]   22   -2
# [8,]   26   -2
# [9,]   30   -2
#[10,]   34   -2
#[11,]   38   -2
#[12,]   42   -2
```

`+` and `-` operations are vectorised so you don't need a `for` loop to do that. Using `head` and `tail` we select combination of current value and next value.